# java.lang.ProcessBuilder throws unsuspected IOException

Tags: java, processbuilder

maybe I'm a little naive, but I guess this is not supposed to behave that way.
First my Code:

```
   private String ExeName="dc64cmd.exe";
   private String Dir=System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") +"\\12noon Display Changer\\";           
   private String DetachArgument = "-monitor=\"PnP-Monitor (Standard)\" -detach";
   try {
        System.out.println(new File(Dir+ExeName).exists()); 
        //This prints "true" as expected.


        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(ExeName, DetachArgument);
        pb=pb.directory(new File(Dir));

        pb=pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb=pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb=pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        //afaik the 3 lines above are not necessary. But just to be sure..

        pb.start();
    } catch (java.io.IOException IOexc) {
        System.err.println(IOexc.toString());
    }
```

The output of the program is

```
true
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dc64cmd.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\12noon Display Changer"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

The last part is the german localized version of "The System can't find the File.

I don't get it why on the one hand the file exists, but on the other hand it can't be found.

I dived a little bit into java.lang.ProcessBuilder and found out, the Exception is actually thrown in java.lang.ProcessImpl.java in line 189

```
handle = create(cmdstr, envblock, path,
                    stdHandles, redirectErrorStream);
```

This Exception leads java.lang.ProcessImpl.Start(...) (beginning at line 83) to close the FileInputStreams and FileOutputStreams in the finally-clause fo the try-statement.
However, while debugging i noticed f2.close() (line141) is called twice, leading to a thrown Exception, which then is interpreted as unkown file.

My first guess would be a bug, but i think my code is rather trivial and shouldn't provoce a unkown bug.

Morelikely I made a stupid little mistake in my code in the first place....

I hope you can read my bad english and my bad style, I'm not used to write about code...

Any help is appreciated.

jdk 1.7.0_03

*edit*: It might be important to mention the file i want to run is a 64 bit executable, although i installed it in the x86-folder.

Comment: Do you need to have administrative privileges to run that program? Try running it manually and see if it asks you for an admin password.

Comment: No, dc64cmd does not need elevated rights.

Comment: Does `new ProcessBuilder(Dir+ExeName, ...)` change the message?

Comment: In fact, the message disappears. But the Process is not startet properly either (if it ran, my secondary screen would be deactivated)

Comment: I have written an answer about the two points.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
new ProcessBuilder(Dir+ExeName, 
     "-monitor=\"PnP-Monitor (Standard)\"", 
     "-detach");
```

This will solve two things:

- You use a full qualified name for the executable.
- Your `detachArgument` seem to be two arguments in fact.

Comment: The IOException is not thrown in this version. Nevertheless the Process is still not startet. Interestingly, if I just try "new ProcessBuilder("calc.exe","");" everything works fine (e.g. calculator is properly started). I dont get it. I wrote similar code in C# and everything worked fine...

Comment: @samjaf; `calc.exe` is searched and found via the `PATH` variable. Your exe isn't found in `PATH` is assume. That's part one. Part two: Did you really try to split your `DetachArgument` in two separate Strings?

Comment: I'm aware that calc is easy found via PATH. I mentioned it to assure that I can start a Process at all. And yes, i splitted the Argument in to sperate arguments. As a matter of fact, I just copied&pasted your snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure this might be the problem

```
pb=pb.directory(new File(Dir));
pb=pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb=pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb=pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

For a start `pb.directory` returns a java.io.File so your just redirecting the output of a file of the directory?

Maybe try this;

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(ExeName, DetachArgument);
pb.directory(new File(Dir));
```

## in German for completeness

Im ziemlich sicher, dass dies das Problem sein könnte

```
 pb = pb.directory (new File (dir));
 pb = pb.redirectError (ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
 pb = pb.redirectOutput (ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
 pb = pb.redirectInput (ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

Für einen Start `pb.directory` gibt einen java.io.File so Ihr gerade Umleiten der Ausgabe einer Datei des Verzeichnisses?

Vielleicht versuchen Sie dies;

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (EXEName, DetachArgument);
 pb.directory (new File (dir));
```

Comment: and btw pb.directory _does_ return another processbuilder-instance. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29